# Java Time Loop - Iteration

Tags: java, time, hashmap

I am in a situation where I need to to iterate through the given time interval.
time is given as a string
ex- 10:33:12 to 11:22:21
I need to iterate through all the seconds in the interval in the string format itself.
What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: convert to seconds, then back to whatever string format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create both date instances, and loop through each second from the first date:

```
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date first = format.parse("10:33:12");
    Date second = format.parse("11:22:21");

    Date next = first;
    do {
        System.out.println(format.format(next));
    } while ((next = new Date(next.getTime() + 1000)).before(second));
```

Note that `next` is modified in the `while` condition and I assumed that values have been validated.

Running that code produces this (truncated) output:

```
10:33:12
10:33:13
10:33:14
10:33:15
...
11:22:17
11:22:18
11:22:19
11:22:20
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use `SimpleDateFormat` and its outdated friends. `Date` is not well suited for time of day alone. And `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome, IMHO no one should use it. I recommend [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. You're welcome to suggest an edit!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the times are in your local time. You can use the `java.time` API for this:

```
String from = "10:33:12", to = "11:22:21";
LocalTime fromTime = LocalTime.parse(from), toTime = LocalTime.parse(to);

for (LocalTime counter = fromTime;
     counter.compareTo(toTime) <= 0;
     counter = counter.plusSeconds(1)) {
    System.out.println(counter.toString());
}
```

The API is very natural - methods like `plusSeconds` give you a lot of freedom to vary the steps that you want to take.

The LocalTime class ignores all issues with Daylight Saving Time, timezones or different calendar systems; it acts like a wall-clock. If you want to take those issues into account, you can look into the other classes in the `java.time` package.

Comment: Good answer. My taste would be for `! counter.isAfter(toTime)` for the comparison (though “not after” is a bit odd of a way to say “before or on”).

Comment: @OleV.V. it's a tricky one. I don't like that there is only `isBefore` and `isAfter` and no variants like `isBeforeOrEquals`. But these two methods are implemented in terms of `compareTo`. I feel that these should be default methods on the `Comparable` interface: `isLessThan`, `isLessThanOrEqual`, `isGreaterThan`, `isGreaterThanOrEquals` and not methods to be added to every class in Java.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know the initial datatype of your time (`String`?) I'd convert it to time like

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); or any other format of your choice.
java.sql.Time timeValue = new java.sql.Time(formatter.parse(your_time).getTime());
```

and the same for your second timeValue

The result will be of type `Long`. now you simply Iterate from `timeValue1` to `timeValue2`.

```
while(timeValue1 < timeValue2) { ... }
```

if you want to print every second now, you just format the time(`Long`) back to `String`.

*Your question is very broad, so the answer is too...*

Answer (score 0):

This answer solves your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48907495/4587961

However, I would make an improvement. Instead of creating a new `Date` or `LocalDateTime` object each time in the while loop, let's convert start date and end date into Long milliseconds, and iterate over integers (longs).

```
Date startDate = parseDate(startDateString);//Date does not have time zone.
long startMillis = startDate.getTime();

Date endDate = parseDate(endDateString);
long endMillis = endDate.getTime();

long startSeconds = startMillis / 1000;
long endSeconds = endMillis / 1000;

long current = startSeconds;
while (current < endSeconds) {
    doYourStuff();//You can build a date from milliseconds and use SimpleDateFormtatter with any timezone to output your date in any time zone.
    current = current + 1;
}
```